# Javascript error in DataTables when using D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, datatable

I have an issue with the utilisation of d3.js and [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/).
I love the render of DataTables so I wanted to use it for a school project where I have to use D3.js.

The problem is when I create the table with D3.js like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L62tpok2/)
I have the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined"

I thought this was because the table was not created yet when I call the     `$('#table').DataTable()` but the `console.log($('#table').html());` shows the correct html code...

I search this error on Google but the issues with the same error were relative to the structure of the table (missing tbody, missing close tag, different column number in thead/tbody etc.) but if I put the html code alone, it work just as expected: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skahr8o8/)

I don't think this is an error with Datatables because it work fine with the same HTML code so maybe I misunderstand something with D3.js ...

Thanks in advance for any leads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `<tr>` on your header row:

```
var thead = d3.select("thead")
  .append("tr") //<-- missing tr
  .selectAll("th")
  .data(d3.keys(stations[0]))
  .enter().append("th").text(function(d) {
    return d
  });
```

Update [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L62tpok2/2/).

In your working version, the browser is correcting the malformed HTML when it parses it:

```
<thead>
  <tr><th>name</th> <!-- what the browser actually renders -->
  <th>city</th>
</tr></thead>
```